# Carousel doesn't show 2 slides per view

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am creating a carousel from scratch using React.

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import './Carousel.css' 
import Image from 'next/image'
import clsx from 'clsx'

const Carousel = ({ images }) => {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0)
  const carouselRef = useRef(null)

  const handleBulletClick = index => {
    setCurrentSlide(index)
    scrollToSlide(index)
  }

  const scrollToSlide = slideIndex => {
    const slideWidth = carouselRef.current.clientWidth
    carouselRef.current.scrollTo({
      left: slideWidth * slideIndex,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <div className="lg:block hidden absolute -bottom-8 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 h-5 w-full">
        <div className="flex gap-2 justify-center mt-2">
          {Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(images.length / 2) }, (_, index) => (
            <button
              key={index}
              className={clsx('carousel-bullet', index === currentSlide && 'active')}
              onClick={() => handleBulletClick(index)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="my-4">
        <div className="carousel-video " ref={carouselRef}>
          {images.map((image, index) => (
            <div className="carousel--slide" key={index}>
              <article className="w-full h-full flex items-center flex-col">
                <Image src={image} alt={image.alt} width={1440} height={500} />
                <h4 className="text-sm opacity-70 pt-2">{image.alt}</h4>
              </article>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Carousel
```

this is my css:

```
:root {
  --carousel-gap: 1rem;
  --slides-per-view-video: 2;
}
.carousel-video {
  scroll-snap-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: var(--carousel-gap, 0);
  --slide-size: calc(
    calc((100% + var(--carousel-gap)) / var(--slides-per-view-video)) - var(--carousel-gap)
  );
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  align-items: stretch !important;
}
.carousel--slide {
  flex: 0 0 var(--slide-size);
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  position: relative;
}
.carousel-bullet {
  width: 16px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.carousel-bullet.active {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

This Carousel does work and paginate as it should, when having even numbers carousel slides (2,4,6... ) and i try to paginate it shows 2 slides per view. But unfortunately when there are odd number of slides (3,5,7... ) when paginating, it won't show 2 slides per view, how can I fix this?

This is a demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u13jbf